# How does the OS find the reasons of the page fault?

Tags: operating-system, page-fault

The page fault in memory may have been raised due to a lot of reasons. In what way is the OS figuring out the type of page fault occurred? This is necessary because different types of page faults needs to be treated differently.

Comment: Please take an OS course, or read some books about it, or some documentation for a specific hardware platform (since this is typically very hardware specific), or just do some searching on the Internet (there are many tens of thousands of resource available).

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Handling says "_..The CPU pushes an error code on the stack before firing a page fault exception.._"